# C++ fstream reading utf-8 charset

Tags: c++, locale, symbols, fstream

I have a text file with Lithuanian symbols, but it won't read it correctly. Instead of Ž I get this �

Setting locales didn't work either

`setlocale(LC_ALL, "Lithuanian");`

What am I missing?

Comment: how do you know that you get a wrong symbol?

Comment: *Never, ever* use visual inspection to diagnose this kind of thing. It only tells you that "something" is wrong. Look at the actual bytes from the input, and the bytes that were read.

Comment: Well, I compare them later in the code and there are bunch of errors. So I've tried to output it and yea.. I get those symbols.

Comment: Beware that you may be able to read the text properly, but if you print it to a console where the settings are wrong, then it will show up in a wrong way

Comment: is this a narrow fstream and are you reading into a utf8 string?  its the fstream opened in binary or text mode?  Show some code with expected input & output.

Answer (score 1):

How is the locale `"Lithuanian"` defined?  In particular, what
encoding is it defined to use?  Depending on this, you may have
to specify the encoding in the locale as well.  Something like
`"Lithuanian.UTF-8"`, perhaps, or
`"Lithuanian_Lithuania.UTF-8"`.  Under Windows, you might have
to use `"65001"` instead of `"UTF-8"`.  (The usual syntax for
a locale name is
`language_location.encoding`.
Modern Windows is gradually moving to the Posix locale names,
where the language and the locality are specified using codes
from ISO 639-1 and ISO 3166-1, but depending on your version,
you may have to use the older, longer names, and the code page,
rather than the encoding.)